# What is the mode of a square waveguide \$TE_{11}\$ that is deformed into a circle?

Tags: propagation, waveguide

I am trying to solve the [2013 paper](https://www.isro.gov.in/sites/default/files/pdf/recruitment/oldquepapers/sc/EC-2013.pdf) set by [ISRO](https://www.isro.gov.in/) for electrical engineers. I want some help to solve Question no 17 is correct.

[image]

So I don't even know how to approach the problem, what will be the new deformed radius? will volume be conserved? Can I say $$r = \frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dominant mode in rectangular waveguide is TE10 and in circular
>   waveguide is TE11.
>
> Rectangular to circular waveguide transition convert dominant TE10
>   mode of rectangular waveguide to TE11 dominant mode of circular
>   waveguide and vice versa.

Source: http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/Rectangular-waveguide-vs-Circular-waveguide.html

Comment: So as per the [circular waveguide's cutoff's](https://i.imgur.com/j0VkNwv.png) TE11 has the lowest cutoff. So it is dominant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Square/Rectangular and circular waveguide are commonly used in antenna feed networks for dual-polarization systems.

•   Their high degree of symmetry enables one to achieve homogenous propagation for both polarization modes. Truncation of the guide cross-section under this condition enables the realization of broadband components for antenna applications, mode conversion, and polarization discrimination.

•   It was observed that a smooth taper from circular to rectangular waveguide preserves the modal structure of both guides. That is, a smooth transition from rectangular to circular waveguide can preserve their common reflection symmetries.

For conversion of square to circular modes, follow the link

[Google Book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=TILVCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq=waveguide%20square%20waveguide%20with%20TE11%20propagation%20mode%20deformed%20into%20a%20circle%20circular%20waveguide%20mode&source=bl&ots=QW2JJyXxcQ&sig=ACfU3U0uyas1SHtCWfmMu1sZdVmwdQagTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiogfPr89PlAhWXV30KHdS_Aio4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=waveguide%20square%20waveguide%20with%20TE11%20propagation%20mode%20deformed%20into%20a%20circle%20circular%20waveguide%20mode&f=false)